# Can we get a flair style that is narrower?

Tags: feature-request, flair

Trying to incorporate the new flair into my blog, however I am finding it too wide to fit easily in the 3 column format. There seems to be a lot of empty space in the middle of the clean theme that could easily be stripped without losing content.

Could we get a new flair theme that is more condensed horizontally? For example the one displayed right below this question would work perfectly.

Comment: @Toronto - Don't understand. Why is it a problem to want to put my SO flair on my blog page. Isn't that precisely the type of usage it is intended for?

Comment: I cannot help you.

Comment: @Toronto - I'd already surmised that much.  Thanks for not trying though.

Comment: Any time, friend.

Comment: I too would love a thinner badge!

Comment: @26 years of Welbog - you're useless...

Comment: @Vampire Aren't vampires scared of *flames*? You should rename yourself "*Troll Welbog*". ;)

Comment: Don't forget [this](https://github.com/rchern/StackFlair/issues/18)!

Answer (score 8):

I now have the perfect answer for you: I have created a new web application that allows you to design your own custom flair from scratch! It's as simple as choosing the size of your flair and dragging-and-dropping components onto it:

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/ (listed [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair) on StackApps)

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, on the left is the toolbar which allows you to specify some attributes for the flair (including size, color, border, etc.). Although it's not visible on the screenshot, you can also customize the color / font / size of each item in your flair.

Once you're done, simply hit 'Save' and you'll wind up with the HTML to embed on your page.

Here is an example of a more narrow flair:

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd2fde77a2ca/stackoverflow/193619?ext=.jpg

This service is still under heavy development, so feedback is appreciated.

Comment: very nice. maybe you consider adding an individual combined SE one as well?

Comment: @Tobias: Possibly.